# Different JMS connection factories instantiation via driver name and URL

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jdbc, spring-jms

Spring JDBC allows to specify in properties file for PROD:

```
jdbc.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
jdbc.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@...
```

and for tests

```
jdbc.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=...
```

Thus it's possible to instantiate needed `java.sql.DataSource` instance depends of configuration settings with generic code

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(
        @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}") String driverClass,
        @Value("${jdbc.url}") String url,
        @Value("${jdbc.username}") String username,
        @Value("${jdbc.password}") String password
) {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(url, username, password);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Is it possible in Spring to configure specific type of `java.jms.ConnectionFactory` via driver and URL properties' strings like in Spring JDBC?

Actually, my goal is to use Tibco connection factory for PROD and ActiveMQ for tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring profiles to pull in a different Bean for tests or you can simply override the connection factory bean with a different one in the test case.

**EDIT**

```
@Bean
public FactoryBean<ConnectionFactory> connectionFactory(@Value("${jms.url}") final String urlProp) {
    return new AbstractFactoryBean<ConnectionFactory>() {

        @Override
        public Class<?> getObjectType() {
            if (urlProp.startsWith("activemq:")) {
                return ActiveMQConnectionFactory.class;
            }
            // ...
            throw new RuntimeException("bad url: " + urlProp);
        }

        @Override
        protected ConnectionFactory createInstance() throws Exception {
            if (urlProp.startsWith("activemq:")) {
                URI uri = new URI(urlProp.substring(urlProp.indexOf(":") + 1));
                return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(uri);
            }
            // ...
            throw new RuntimeException("bad url: " + urlProp);
        }

    };

}
```

and

```
jms.url=activemq:vm://localhost
```

Comment: This is exactly what we do. But now I would like to have more flexibly solution.

Comment: More flexible in what way? You can create a simple factory bean to return a different implementation based on a property value. But it seems overkill to me.

Comment: Our app is kind of a black box with config in properties. For implementing end-to-end testing it's good to have ability to change infra implementations with only properties file change.